# How to convert mysql::value::Value to other data type like f64, i32 .. in Rust?

Tags: mysql, rust

I'm trying to get the data from the MySQL Row, the code as below

```
conn.query_iter("select * from TheForm")
    .unwrap()
    .for_each(|row| {
        println!("{:?}", &row.unwrap().unwrap());
    });
```

The output as something like that:

```
[Bytes("16376158.."), Bytes("55683.3"), Bytes("55739.7"), Bytes("55705.8"), Bytes("55717.7"), Bytes("5.21118")]
```

How can I get the data from the Array, like If I want the first index in the array, I print `&row.unwrap().unwrap()[0]`, and the output is `Bytes("16376158..")`, How do I convert the Bytes to the f64, String ot other type?

Comment: what mysql client are you using?

Comment: @DanielA.White MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE???

Comment: i mean the library you are using _in rust_

Comment: @DanielA.White mysql="*"

Comment: There's a free function to take care of converting values: https://docs.rs/mysql/21.0.2/mysql/fn.from_value.html But it seems the values you get from the DB are actually byte arrays, and you'll have to implement the parsing yourself? Not sure…

Comment: you could also use `from_row` to get it to a struct.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you can run a query and read the result set. One way is to read a vector of tuples:

```
let q = "SELECT some_int, some_text FROM some_table";
let mut tx = conn.start_transaction(TxOpts::default())?;
let rows: Vec<(i32, String)> = tx.query(q)?;
for r in rows {
    let my_int = r.0;
    let my_str = r.1;
}
```

You can see more examples in the [docs](https://docs.rs/mysql/21.0.2/mysql/), like this one:

```
let selected_payments = conn
    .query_map(
        "SELECT customer_id, amount, account_name from payment",
        |(customer_id, amount, account_name)| {
            Payment { customer_id, amount, account_name }
        },
    )?;
```

There are also other methods for running queries. Take a look at the `query*` and `exec*` methods in the docs.